# Prove: There exists a function $g(x)$ s.t. $\int_a^\infty g(x)dx$ diverges and $\int_a^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence

I am struggling to prove the following statement:

Let $f(x)$ be a positive function s.t. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Prove:

There exists a function $g(x)$ s.t. $\int_a^\infty g(x)dx$ diverges and $\int_a^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$ converges.

I think the point of the question is to show, That not matter how slowly $f$ goes to zero, We can always find a close enough to convergence $g$ s.t. that the integral of the $f(x)g(x)$ converges.

I am not sure how to approach the question.

I somehow need to find a function $g$ s.t. the integral converges, But i don't know anything about $f$, Besides it goes to zero.

Any hints will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists $x_n$ incerasing to $\infty$ such that $f(x) <\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ fo $x \geq x_n$. Let $g(x)=\frac  1{n (x_{n+1}-x_n)}$ for $x_n \leq x <x_{n+1}$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x$ is not in any of the intervals $(x_n,x_{n+1})$. Then $\int g(x)dx$ is divergent but $\int f(x)g(x)dx$ is convergent.